# Why not putting the definition of classes serialization in a shared package results in a `ClassNotFoundException`?

Tags: java, serialization, classnotfoundexception

I have a client and server which use serialization to send an array of `Shape` from server to client. I have written all code and there is no error in them as far as a create a shared package between client program and the server program. However when I create two separate projects and for each if the projects I create `Shape.java` with the same content as the other one has but this time as I connect client to server it gives me a `ClassNotFoundException`.
Why on the earth it doesn't give error when I put `Shape.java` in a shared package but as soon as I create a copy and paste that to Server's program, it gives me `ClassNotFoundException`? I really need that because I want to send my code to my friend and he has a seperate project using this serialized object.

Comment: Probably because you're not creating it in the same package.

Comment: Yeah, thats my question why should I create it in the same package even when I put the definition of `Shape` in the target project?

Comment: Same package as in `foo.bar.baz.Shape`.

Comment: A number of reasons - the JVM must think it's the _same `class`_. The class must be in the same package and must have the same `serialVersionUID` - if you do not provide this then it is automatically generated; this automatic generation depends on the structure of the source code - a different ordering of declared variables, for example, can cause this to differ.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, the code is all the same, what else needs to be specified?

Comment: The most import question is _why_ would you want to not have shared code? Given that the code has to be the same, sharing libraries is much better than copy/pasta.

Comment: As noted in the question I'm sending my project to someone who hasn't all my project and his written his own.

Comment: One of the reasons why java serialization has very limited use cases. It would be better to use a different serialization/object binding library, e.g. json with jackson.

Comment: Yeah `JSON` is much powerful if this is the case about serialization .. :|

Comment: @k5_ "_very limited use cases_" - **nonsense**.

Comment: Slow compared to other binary formats like protobuf. Unsecure so not really usable for public apis. Problems with interface evolution(so no long term storage either). Besides jvm internal use (e.g. inter classloader communication), or apis in trusted networks no good use cases come to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why should I create [the class] in the same package?

Because `Shape` is *not* the name of the class, only a part of it. Java identifies classes by their full name, which includes package.

If you define `Shape` on the server as `com.myserver.Shape` and on the client as `com.myclient.Shape`, JVM would correctly treat the two classes as unrelated.

A common approach is to make a special package for your data exchange objects, e.g. `com.shared.dto.Shape`, and use it on both sides of communication.

If you need to share your project with someone else, make a separate jar with your DTOs, and another jar with the client library. Build the client code using the client library and the DTO jar. This will ensure that the client would be able to communicate with the server built against the same DTO jar.

Comment: Thanks for the note, If he makes the name of his package to something like mine, would the error get fixed?

Comment: @ehsan Yes, if you use the same package name on both sides, the error would get fixed. It is better, however, to use the same file to avoid problems caused by modifying one side but not the other. It is a good idea to give your class serialization version ID as well.

Comment: Thanks, and I added : `private static final long serialVersionUID = 20L;`, and forgive me, my voting is locked as I upvote much ;)